# Making a fixed div have freely moving text when re-sizing browser

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a header set up as fixed, so that it will always be at the top of the page when scrolling, however when the browser window is re-sized, the full header doesn't show. It is fixed, but I want the horizontal scroll to show the full header. I just need help in doing that. I tried the alternative position attributes but it failed to accomplish what I wanted, alongside my attempt with float.

Here's the html `

```
    <div id="container">
        <header>  
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </header>


        <div id="content">
        <nav>
            <div id="logo"> 
                <img  src="Images/Logo.png" >
            </div>                  

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Index.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-HOME fa-2x" id="on"></i>  <!--this is using the font awesome icons, reffered to in the head. Multiple divs are used as the websote declared it should be done. Purely used for the icons -->
                        <span class="nav-text" id="on">
                            HOME
                        </span>
                    </a>                      
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="standards&info.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            STANDARDS & INFORMATION
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="interesting_info.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            INTERESTING INFORMATION
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="JOBS.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            JOBS
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="photo&video.HTML">
                        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            PHOTOS & <BR> VIDEOS
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>

        <footer> 
            <h4>&copy;  2015</h4>
        </footer>
    </div>`
```

And heres the CSS

```
    @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);


html, body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: rgb(110, 110, 110);
padding:0;
margin:0;
min-width:1280px;
}
#container{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.fa-2x{
    font-size:2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-left:10px;
}
nav {
background:rgb(255, 90, 9);
position:fixed;
top:0;
height:calc(100% - 40px);
min-height:600px;
left:0;
width:80px;
overflow:hidden;
transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
transition:all .1s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
-moz-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-moz-transition:all .1s linear;
-ms-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
float:left;
z-index:100;
}
nav:hover{
width:200px;
transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
transition:all .1s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
-moz-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-moz-transition:all .1s linear;
-ms-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);;
}
nav li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}
#on{
    color:#41A3A3;
}
nav li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
transition:all .1s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
-moz-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-moz-transition:all .1s linear;
-ms-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);

transition:all .1s linear;
margin-top: calc(100% / 8);
}
nav .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display: table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}
.nav-text {
position:relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:180px;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
font-size:14px;
}
nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    margin-left:80px;

    width:100%;
   height:113px; 
   background:rgb(57, 57, 57);
   z-index:90;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    color:white;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:129px;
}
footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
   width:100%;  
   height:40px; 
    background:rgb(57, 57, 57);
    line-height:0px;
}
h4{
    font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:20px;
}
h2{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#BFBFBF;
}
#content{
height:calc(100% - 160px);
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
top:114px;
}

.twobox{
    width:35%;
    height:96%;
    top:0;
    margin-right:4%;
    margin-left:6%;
    float:left;
}
.title{
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    height:70px;
    margin-bottom:8%;
    margin-top:6%;
    width:100%:
}
.info{
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:auto%;
    padding-left:4%;
    padding-right:4%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.infojob{
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:auto%;
    padding-left:4%;
    padding-right:4%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    height:600px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
hr{
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    opacity: 0.0001;
}
p{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color:#BFBFBF;
    font-size:18px;
}
#onebox{
    width:40%;
    height:96%;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    margin-left:26%;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.threebox{
    width:20%;
    height:94%;
    top:0;
    margin-right:4%;
    margin-left:6%;
    float:left;
}
.row{
    display: inline-block;
    height:170px;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top:60px;
    min-width:1120px;
}
#rows{
    display: inline-block;
    height:390px;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top:60px;
    min-width:1120px;

}
.read_more{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color:#E50000;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity:0.8;
}
h3{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color:#BFBFBF;
    font-size:30px;
}
h5{
    font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#BFBFBF;
    text-align:center;
}
a:link {
color:#efefef;
}
a:visited {
color:#efefef;
}
a:hover {
    color:#52CCCC;
}
.boxmore{
    width:18%;
    height:170px;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    float:left;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-left:4%;
    border-radius:0px 0px 30px 30px;

}
.box{
    width:18%;
    height:170px;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    float:left;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-left:4%;

}
.center{
    margin-left:42%;
    width:260px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    margin-bottom:15px;

}
.wraps{
    width:220px;
    height:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 910px ) / 4);
}
.discriptions{
    width:220px;
    height:60px;
    margin-top:310px;
    margin-left:43px;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
.discriptionvid{
    width:240px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
.rowvid{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left:3%;
    margin-left:6%;
    height:280px;
    width:calc( (560px * 2) + (20px * 2));
}
.media{
    width:240px;
    height:280px;
    margin-left:38px;
    float:left;
}
.standard{
        width:30%;
        min-width:20%;
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-bottom:100px;
        border-spacing:0px;
        padding:10px;
}
.centered{
    margin-left:40%;
    width:260px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#7E4A00;
}
.standard th {
        width:200px;
        border-bottom:solid #000000;
        padding:20px;
        background:#7E4A00;
        height:50px;
}
.standard td  {
        border-bottom:dashed #000000;
        padding: 0px 10px;
        height:170px;
        min-height:170px;

        min-width:365px;

    }
.left{
        width:40%;
    }
.mid {
        border:1px;
        border-right:solid #000000;
        border-left:solid #000000;

    }

    .involves{
        height:144px;
        background-color:#7E4A00;
        width:60%;
        margin-top:0%;
        margin-left:19%;
        padding:1px;
    }
    .small{
        height:30px;
        background-color:#7E4A00;
        width:60%;
        margin-top:0%;
        margin-left:4%;
        margin-bottom:14.5px;
    }

    .small_ind{
        margin-top:0%;
        height:30px;
        margin-bottom:105px ;
        background-color:#7E4A00;
        width:60%;
        margin-left:18%;
    }
```

[And here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j33ws19f/)

It isn't displaying properly as font awesome isn't working, so the nav seems a bit out of sorts. You can still see the issue with the header though, if you minimise the screen size.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this CSS:

```
html, body{min-width:1280px;}
header{margin-left:80px;
h1{padding-left:129px;}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j33ws19f/1/)

Comment: Yeah I tried this fix but it didn't accomplish what I wanted. Thank  you for having a go at it.